# Update a child's data component to the father component in vue.js using .vue webpack(vue2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am testing the components of `vue.js` and I encountered the problem of updating a parent component when the child changes.

I have generated the project with vue-cli (webpack), and I am using components that have their own `.vue` file.

The code:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
     <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
      <div class="pie">
       <change-title :title="title"></change-title>
     </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>      
  import ChangeTitle from './components/ChangeTitle'

  export default {
    components: {
      ChangeTitle
    },
    data () {
      return {
        title: 'The title'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**ChangeTitle.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="title">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title']
}
</script>
```

**The problem**
When the application load displays the title attribute correctly, but when I type in the `<change-title>` component field the title attribute that is directly in the `App.vue` file is not updated.

Also it shows me the following message:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
>   overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
>   data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
>   mutated: "title"

What is the way to connect the child component with its parent component?

Thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vuejs update parent data from child component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component)

Comment: It can not be taken as duplicate, since the link you indicate does not use component with its own file and does not use .vue extension

Comment: But answer will be same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40915910/1610034) for you as well, also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41663544/1610034)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make a copy of the `prop` and place in data and then bind to that using `v-model` because `Vue` doesn't want you to directly change the prop from inside the component, so, inside the `created` hook simply copy the `prop` to an attribute in data:

```
export default{
  props: ['title'],
  created() {
    this.val = this.title
  },
  data() {
    return {
      val: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Then bind to it using `v-model`:

```
<input v-model="val">
```

You next step is to send the data back to the parent when the value changes, which you can do inside a `watcher`, simply watch `val` inside your `change-title` component and `$emit` it:

```
  watch: {
    val() {
      this.$emit('title-updated', this.val);
    }
  }
```

Then  you can listen for that event in in your parent like so:

```
<change-title :title="title" @title-updated="updateTitle">
```

And finally add the `updateTitle` method to change the `title` in your parent:

```
  methods: {
    updateTitle(title) {
      this.title = title;
    }
  }
```

Here's the JSFiddle for the entire thing: https://jsfiddle.net/90ws3sL6/