# Can I get computed data from child component to parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way to get computed data from child component to parent component? Because I'm sending the data from parent to child first and then I want to use the comuted property (data) in the parent component. I want to do that because I want to reuse that important component (child) in other components too.

I have a search input field for filtering my items, and when i wrote something down i wanna get back that list from the child component.

Parent component

```
<input class="form-control form-control-search m-input" autocomplete="off" type="text" v-on:input='testFunc()' v-model="search" placeholder="Search...">
<paginate-links v-if="items.length > 0" :models="items">
  <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline" v-for="item in filterItems" v-bind:key="item.id">
    {{ item.title }}
  </div>
</paginate-links>
```

Child component

```
props: ['item']
computed: {
    filterItems () {
      return filter // here goes my code
    }
}
```

So can i get the `filterItems` in the parent component?

Comment: [Sending Messages To Parents With Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update parent model from child component Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663010/update-parent-model-from-child-component-vue)

Comment: Can you clarify `comuted property (data)`? they're not the same. computed property is a reactive cached value that you can utilise a hook on, with data, you use `watch` to add hooks

Comment: Sorry i meant just computed property. Because im getting something back with it right? Thats why I wrote data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can send data back to the parent, but probably the easiest way I'd say is using an emit within the computed.

in child:

```
computed:{
  myVal() {
    let temp = this.num + 1;
    this.$emit('onNumChange', temp);
    return temp;
  }
}
```

in parent template:

```
<my-child-component @onNumChange="changeHandler"/>
```

in parent script

```
methods: {
  changeHandler(value) {
    console.log('Value changed to: ', value);
  }
}
```

You could do a similar thing with `watch`, or pass a function from parent as a prop that notifies the parent, but my recommended way would be to use vuex

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/

Comment: That example you wrote i need to set that in the parent component or the child component?

Comment: also, as mentioned in the comments, the duplicate question pointed out has an answer with a working example https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/QdKKBa?editors=1010

Comment: I made it. Thanks a lot. :)