# VueJS passing computed value from component to parent

Tags: vue.js

I've made a VueJS component that operates some `<select>` elements. The result of this UI is that the user selects a value.

I have a function in the compoent's `computed` for showing the user's selected value on screen.

How do I pass this value back to the parent VueJS thingy?

It seems to be something to so with `$emit` but I don't see that I have an event.

I've tied to raise one as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413352/can-i-get-computed-data-from-child-component-to-parent-component), but nowt happens.

In the component:

```
        computed: {
            selectedCode: function () {
                var selected = '(No code selected.)';
                if (this.category) { selected = this.category; }
                if (this.code) { selected = this.code; }

                this.$emit('selectedCode', selected);

                return selected;
            },
```

In the parent Vue app:

```
<code-selector v-bind:code="code" v-on:selectedCode="codeSelect"></sic-selector>
```

and

```
                methods:
                {
                    selectedCode: function (z) {
                        console.log(z);
                    },
```

Comment: So the computed function doesn't run if its value isn't used in the HTML, but that's still not fixed it.

So: I'm definitely hitting the `$emit` function, but still nothing is happening in the parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is mainly because of emitting a camelCased event name. So, as mentioned in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names):

> If emitting a camelCased event name:
>
> ```
> this.$emit('myEvent')
> ```
>
> Listening to the kebab-cased version will have no effect:
>
> ```
> <!-- Won't work -->
> <my-component v-on:my-event="doSomething"></my-component>
> ```
>
> Unlike components and props, event names will never be used as variable or property names in JavaScript, so there’s no reason to use camelCase or PascalCase. Additionally, `v-on` event listeners inside DOM templates will be automatically transformed to lowercase (due to HTML’s case-insensitivity), so `v-on:myEvent` would become `v-on:myevent` – making `myEvent` impossible to listen to.
>
> For these reasons, we recommend you **always use kebab-case for event names**.

So, just emit a kebab-case event name like:

```
this.$emit('selected-code', selected);
```

and then you can easily listen to it like:

```
<code-selector v-on:selected-code="codeSelect"></code-selector>
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ getCount }} times.</button>',
  computed: {
     getCount: function () {
        this.$emit('selected-code', this.count);
        return this.count;
     }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: {},
  methods: {
    codeSelect(z) {
      console.clear()
      console.log(z);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <button-counter v-on:selected-code="codeSelect"></button-counter>
</div>
```

**Note:** Please note that the demo shared in the answer in the question that you have shared in your post [Can I get computed data from child component to parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50413662/1823841) on [codepen](https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/QdKKBa?editors=1010), has a simple emitted event name like:

```
this.$emit('update', e.target.valueAsNumber)
```

Thus the code is working in that demo.