# vue how to access v-model from child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

my child component is like this

```
<editor v-model="edit_thread.body"></editor>
```

and then I access the component from inside like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input :value="this.value">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                value: this.edit_thread.body
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

not working, I miss something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update parent model from child component Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663010/update-parent-model-from-child-component-vue)

Answer (score 7):

To [use `v-model` on custom components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components), the component needs to:

- have a [`prop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) (not a [`data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) property) named `value`:

  ```html
   <template>
     <div>
       <input :value="value">
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
     props: ['value']
   }
   </script>
  ```
- and [emit an `input` event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) with new values:

  ```html
   <template>
     <div>
       <input @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
     </div>
   </template>
  ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/43x98zmop7)