# How to pass v-model value between components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework, v-model

I have a parent form component and a child. How do I pass data from one to another using v-model? *They are in different files*. I'm using the components of the Quasar Framework.

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
  <q-input
    label="Nome *"
    lazy-rules
    :rules="[val => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Por favor, digite o seu nome']"
    v-model="nome"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Nome",
  data() {
    return {
      nome: "Max"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 500px">
  <q-form @reset="onReset" class="q-gutter-md">
      <Nome> </Nome>              
      <div>
   <q-btn label="Reset" type="reset" color="red" flat class="q-ml-sm" />
      </div>
    </q-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Nome from "components/Nome.vue";
export default {
  components: { Nome },  

  onReset() {
    this.name = null;
  }
};
</script>
```

How do I *onReset()* work?

*Automatically translated.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vue how to access v-model from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472074/vue-how-to-access-v-model-from-child-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some confusion about your child component and parent component. On your code `Nome` is the child component and the form that using `Nome` is the parent component.

You can use `ref` to call the reset method on `Nome` from the parent form component.

Here is a Working example -

```js
Vue.component("nome-input", {
 data(){
   return {
     input: ""
    }
  },
  template: `
  <input @input="onInput" type="text" v-model="input">
  `,
  methods: {
   reset(){
     this.input = ""
    },
    onInput(){
     this.$emit('onInput', this.input);
    }
  }
});
Vue.component("user-form", {
 data(){
   return {
     name: '',
    }
  },
  components: {
  },
  template: `
  <div>
   {{name}}
    <nome-input ref="nome" @onInput="updateName"></nome-input>
    <button @click.prevent="save">Save</button>
    <button @click.prevent="reset">reset</button>
  </div>
  `,
  methods: {
   save(){
     console.log(this.name);
    },
    reset(){
     this.name = "";
     this.$refs.nome.reset();
    },
    updateName(value){
     this.name = value;
    }
  }
  
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <user-form></user-form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle link for the above codes https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/u4x9jw62/34/