# How do I access v-model in vue-class-component

Tags: vue.js, vue-class-components

I want to use the new Vue syntax from https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component. Unfortunately, I have trouble accessing the value that's passed with `v-model`. I can instead declare a @value property to pass the value but that seems a bit inconsistent given that there are a lot of existing uses of `v-model` in my codebase.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{value}}
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue"
import Component from "vue-class-component"
import { Prop } from "vue-property-decorator"

@Component
export default class Display extends Vue {
    @Prop() value!: string
    // lifecycle hook
    mounted() {alert("The value is " + this.value)}
}
</script>
```

The current code can be accessed with:

```
<Display :value="myVar"/>
```

I'd like to access via:

```
<Display v-model="myVar"/>
```

Comment: Add your code..

Comment: Add the code you have achieved so far and I will be happy to help you.

Comment: What you want to do is, access the value value and change it to your liking without using v-model?

Comment: @DiesanRomero I want to not have to use "@Prop() value!: " but instead access v-model.

Comment: If you want to access to v-model you need a kind of input.

Comment: @DiesanRomero I added a few additional lines. Is it now clear to you what behavior I expect?

Comment: Try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472074/vue-how-to-access-v-model-from-child-component

Comment: @DiesanRomero That link is about the old syntax.