# How to pass data from child to parent in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token'); 
              axios.get(baseUrl+'/country/fetch/'+id)
              .then((response) => {



                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Please help me to pass data from child to parent. Here I am getting data as response. Now I want to pass this to parent How can I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update parent model from child component Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663010/update-parent-model-from-child-component-vue)

Answer (score 0):

Vue has a simple approach for that.

From parent to child: Use Props

From child to parent: Use Events

That means your childComponent should call in the `then` part:

```
this.$emit('newData', response)
```

And your parentComponent should listen to it with:

Markup

```
<childComponent @newData="handleNewData"/>
```

ComponentCode

```
methods: {
    handleNewData(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
}
```