# vue.js v-select default value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-select

I want to make a default value of the select option using vue.js

here is my code

```
 <v-select
        v-model="contact.title"
        :options="['Mr','Mrs','Ms']">
      </v-select>
```

and

```
export default {
 props: {
  contact: {
  type: Object,
  required: true,
 },

titles: {
     type: Array,
     required: true,
   },
  },
};
```

thanks

Comment: Just set a default value for the `title` field of the `contact` object passed as prop.

Comment: You have to set the the value of `contract.title` to one of the values from the array `['Mr','Mrs','Ms']`

Comment: this will fire an error, since props don't support two ways binding

Comment: @mava answer looks good, I completly missed that it's props

Answer (score 4):

Try this.I think this will work.

```
<v-select
  v-model="selected"
  :options="options">
</v-select>


data: () {
  return {
    selected: 'Option 1',
    options: ["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

[Mutating a prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated) is not best practice in vue.
You could do it like:

```
<v-select
    v-model="selected"
    :options="['Mr','Mrs','Ms']">
</v-select>


data: function () {
  return {
    selected: '' || 'defaultValue'
  }
},
```

This way you are not mutating the prop and you easily can set a default value.
If you want to pass the data to the parent look at:
[Pass data to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663010/update-parent-model-from-child-component-vue)

Comment: What is not working? The default value? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: yes the default value can't display, nothing errors in the console